# How to run a bash command regardless of spaces

Tags: c, bash, shell, space

I am working on a C program, with system commands. I have configured it to sh -c . This does not work with commands with spaces. Is there a command to run a command with spaces over shell regardless if it has spaces. I am currently using the sh -c command, like so:

```
char s[500];
  strcpy (s, "sh -c");
  strcat (s, i);
  system (s);
```

Comment: use `exec*` instead, or posix_spawn

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and [mcve].

Comment: Did I not comply with the rules?

Comment: BTW, see the [mcve] guidelines -- ideally, a question should include (1) a **runnable** example (that is, code complete enough that it can be copied and pasted without other work to run), (2) *desired* output (meaning that the program actually needs to be complete enough that it *should* generate specific output when run), and (3) *actual* output... while being the shortest thing that meets those criterial (as described in the coverage for "minimal", or in "tricks for trimming" at http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I would rather not put my entire program on there, but I will try to make it runnable but it might be better to do so.

Comment: We don't *want* your entire program -- that would be out of compliance with the "minimal" part of the guidelines. We want the shortest possible complete and runnable program that illustrates the problem. That's two separate criteria that should both be simultaneously met: (1) shortest possible; (2) complete and runnable.

Answer (score 1):

`system(str)` **always** invokes `sh -c "$str"`. That's what it does.

What you're doing here is `sh -c "sh -c$str"`. Why this is broken should, in that context, be obvious.

Also, `sh` is not bash -- on many operating systems it's a completely different shell, like `ash` or `dash`, and even where it's provided by the `bash` package, it runs in a POSIX-compatibility mode with different features when invoked under the `sh` name.

---

If you want to invoke bash from your C program, don't use `system()` at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Here's our actual shell script.
 * Note that it's a constant string; this is CRITICAL for security.
 * Do not UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES concatenate untrusted data with this string; instead,
 * use placeholders ($1, $2, etc) to pull in other data.
 */
const char* bash_script = "printf '%s\n' \"First argument: $1\" \"Second argument: $2\"";

int main(void) {

    int pid = fork();                /* if we didn't fork, execlp() would end our program */
    if (pid == 0) {                  /* if we're the child process fork() created...      */
        execlp("bash",                    /* command to invoke; in exec*p, found in PATH  */
               "bash", "-c", bash_script, /* actually running bash with our script        */
               "bash",                    /* $0 for the script is "bash"; "_" also common */
               "Argument One",            /* $1 for the script                            */
               "Argument Two",            /* $2 for the script                            */
               NULL                       /* NUL terminator for argument list             */
        );
    } else {
        int exit=0;
        waitpid(pid, &exit, 0);
        printf("Shell exited with status: %d\n", exit);
    }
}
```

You can see this running at https://ideone.com/UXxH02

Comment: No. The quotes are for illustrative purposes, to generate a shell command equivalent to what `system()` is doing. If `s="echo hello"`, then `system(s)` does the same thing as running `sh -c 'echo hello'` does at your shell.

Comment: ...thing is, `system()` with non-constant arguments is massively insecure. Let's say that `hello` comes from a string -- if instead of containing `hello` that string contained `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`, you couldn't ever concatenate it into a string that a POSIX-compliant `sh` instance *wouldn't* treat as an instruction to run `rm` as a subprocess.

Comment: ...so, for the `echo hello` example, the **safe** way to execute is by doing a `fork()`, then a `execlp("echo", "echo", "hello", NULL);` inside the child -- no `system()` at all.

Comment: ...that said, if you **really** want a shell, you can do that: `execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", "echo \"$1\"", "_", "hello", NULL);`